# how to redirect to my customized swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui, springfox

Currently I am integrating springfox (swagger) in maven web application. I have customized the swagger-ui.html and placed the swagger-ui.html inside the src/main/webapp/static directory. I am able to load the swagger-ui.html using the filename (URL:http://localhost:7999/myApp/swagger-ui.html). However I need to load the swagger-ui.html using redirecting url like http://localhost:7999/myApp/documentation/. Can you please make me to understand how we can do this using springfox. Following is my mvc resources configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="/WEB-INF/static/swagger-ui.html"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```